# If $\alpha$ is a cycle of length $k$. Then $o(\alpha)=k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found a proof of this theorem wich says:

$ Proof: $ If $ \alpha=(i_1,i_2,...,i_{k-1},i_{k}) $ . Then,

$\alpha^{k}(i_j)=\alpha^{j}\alpha^{k-j}(i_j)=\alpha^{j}(i_k)=i_j, \; \forall\; j $

Thus, $ \alpha^{k} =1$ and $ o(\alpha) \leq k $.

Now, if $ 1\leq s < k $. Then, $ \alpha^{s}(i_1)=i_{s+1}\neq i_1 $. Therefore, $ o(\alpha) = k $

My problem is in the last line. I don't get how concludes that $o(\alpha)=k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume  $\alpha$ is a cycle of length $k \gt 1$.

It is easy to see that $\alpha^k$ is the identity so $1 \le o(\alpha) \le k$

> Now, if $ 1\leq s < k $. Then, $ \alpha^{s}(i_1)=i_{s+1}\neq i_1 $. So $ \alpha^{s}$ is not the identity permutation.

So the order is indeed equal to $k$.